# sql support for []time.Time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have a postgres table as:

```
CREATE TABLE public.foo
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    foo timestamp with time zone[],
    bar timestamp with time zone
)
```

I'm then querying this table and scanning the result into values as:

```
var res []myResStruct
rows, err := db.Query(`sql goes here`, &params)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("err querying: %v\n", err)
    panic(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    var (
        id   uuid.UUID
        foo  []uint8
        bar  time.Time
    )
    if err := rows.Scan(&id, &foo, &bar); err != nil {
        log.Printf("err scanning: %v\n", err)
        panic(err)
    }

    // note: I hate this, but golang's sql driver doesn't support \
    //       arrays of timestamps?
    s := string(foo)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "{", "", -1)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "}", "", -1)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "\"", "", -1)
    z := strings.Split(s, ",")
    var tmpFoo []time.Time
    for _, v := range z {
        t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05-07", v)
        tmpFoo = append(tmpFoo, t)
    }

    // note @adam-hanna: is there a way to know the length of results \
    //                   so I can create a slice of proper length?
    res = append(res, &myResStruct{
        id:   id,
        foo:  tmpFoo,
        bar:  bar,
    })
}

if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("rows.Error(): %v\n", err)
    panic(err)
}
```

Why do I have to use `[]uint8` for `foo` but I can use `time.Time` for `bar`? Is there a better way? FYI - I'm using [lib/pq](https://github.com/lib/pq).

Comment: [Looks like it's not supported by lib/pq](https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/536). Dang.

Comment: Replying to "is there a way to know the length of results so I can create a slice of proper length?" - Don't know of anything, but sqlx can make your life of reading into a slice simpler: http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/ (see "Get and Select")

Comment: I can only recommend https://github.com/jackc/pgx which supports time.Time out of the box.